# Handler change Session Variable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, session-variables, httphandler

I have this handler:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim request As HttpRequest = context.Request
    Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response

    If (request.QueryString(GestioneConstants.PASSWORD_PARAM) Is Nothing) Then

        Dim erroreParamName = GestioneConstants.ERRORE_PASSWORD_PARAM
        Dim erroreMessage = GestioneConstants.MESSAGE_PWD_MANCANTE

        Dim urlHome = "~/Default.aspx?" & erroreParamName & "=" & erroreMessage

        response.Redirect(urlHome, False)
    Else
        Dim passToFind= request.QueryString(GestioneConstants.PASSWORD_PARAM)
        Dim myConn As OdbcConnection
        myConn = New OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=SERVER;uid=uid;pwd=password")

        myConn.Open

        Dim passwordQuery As String = "SELECT PASSWORD as PASSWORD FROM INFOPWD WHERE INFOPWD.PASSWORD = '" & passToFind & "'"
        Dim queryCommand As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(passwordQuery,myConn)


        Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader()

        Dim risultato = ""
        While reader.Read()

            risultato = reader("PASSWORD").ToString

        End While

        reader.Close
        myConn.Close

        If (risultato Is "") Then
            Dim erroreParamName = GestioneConstants.ERRORE_PASSWORD_PARAM
            Dim erroreMessage = GestioneConstants.MESSAGE_PWD_ERRATA

            Dim urlHome = "~/Default.aspx?" & erroreParamName & "=" & erroreMessage

            response.Redirect(urlHome, False)
        Else

            context.Session("Logged") = True

            Dim strURL = "~/Home.aspx"

            response.Redirect(strURL, False)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Pratically my problem its on:

```
context.Session("Logged") = True
```

I just want to set this session variable to `true` where from the ASP page the user insert the correct password.

But I get the error:

```
An object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Can someone help?

Comment: You've not shown your complete class. Is you class also marked as implementing [`IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Current` property: 
`context.Current.Session("Logged") = True` should work.

Comment: the `context` *parameter* passed to the `ProcessRequest` method *is* the "current" context. All that doing `context.Current` does is possibly add a warning about accessing a static property via an instance rather than the type.